# Specify sub folder creation path based on cell value

Tags: excel, vba

How could I change the path for the folder and its subfolders created on the code below based on a cell value?

-Create a main folder representing month/year Ex. "0820"

-Create sub folders for all defined tasks for this month and save them in "0820"
-When it is a new month I would like to just run the macro and have next month's folder created "0920" and the new monthly tasks sub folders will be created under this folder structure.

I do not know how to code the path to saved sub folders to based on cell value, instead of a hard defined path that I would have to modify every month or manually transfer new folders.

Here is what I have to create the task folders, but this does not allow for a flexible sub folder.

```
Sub CreatePMIDFolders() 'Excel VBA to make a folder.

Dim i As Integer
On Error Resume Next

For i = 2 To 1000
MkDir "C:\PM_CM_Cdrive\PM_CM Uploads_Cdrive\" & Range("M" & i)
Next i

End Sub
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Try:

`MkDir "C:\PM_CM_Cdrive\PM_CM Uploads_Cdrive\" & Format(Month(Date), "00") & Right(Year(Date), 2)`

This will autoupdate itself when a new month comes in.

Comment: @P J: You need to check if the folder it's created with this syntax, if not create it prior to the loop for the subfolders as stated with this comment. @Foxfire: Perhaps the answer could be more useful if included the way to do what I stated.